# Hibernate cannot open connection while redirect port with iptables

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, redirect

I have two website using Struts2 with Hibernate, deploy on Ubuntu with Tomcat 7.
Tomcat server run with port 80, i use "iptables" of Ubuntu to redirect port 8080 to 80 :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

After a few of first requests on port 80 and 8080 website run normal, one of website (some time both of two) has error with hibernate occur message "Cannot open connection"
Here is my hibernate configuration file of two website :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="dtasoft">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://<serverip>/<dbname>?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"><dbuser></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"><dbpassword></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">99</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>  

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>


        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Models here -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is error :

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99) at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52) at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449) at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160) at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81) at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473) at com.anhdt.website.dao.AbstractSimpleGenericDao.<init>(AbstractSimpleGenericDao.java:38) at com.anhdt.website.dao.BlogDao.<init>(BlogDao.java:28) at com.anhdt.website.action.BlogArticle.execute(BlogArticle.java:79) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at com.anhdt.website.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:61) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2238) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2159) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792) at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:615) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:167) at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133) at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) ... 78 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.99' (using password: YES) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4101) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1300) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2337) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2177) ... 92 more
```

Any one please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand you. What's the reason for redirect 8080 to 80 port?

MySql is running on localhost too? In this case you should use another port.

Mysql usually listen on 3306. You could configure hibernate.url parameter with:

```
jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/<db_name>
```